# How secure is the WPF PasswordBox, really?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, security, passwordbox

I've already asked a couple of questions around the `PasswordBox` recently, but at the heart of my issue, I need an extremely secure way of getting very sensitive information inputted into my .Net application.

Out of the box, the WPF `PasswordBox` is the go to control for getting passwords, or other sensitive information. For the sake of security, it provides a `SecureString` object through the `SecurePassword` property which is, in my case, secure enough for my needs.  However, there is one major flaw that I see with this control-- it has a `Password` property which is the user-entered content in an insecure .Net string.

I would like to assume that if I never access the `Password` property within my application, an insecure version of my sensitive information will never be generated and have to be garbage collected.  That fine.  However, since the point of the secured form of the string is to keep the value secure from a snooping process (I assume) that can read the .Net memory, could the same snooping malicious codes simply look for a `PasswordBox` that is hanging around in memory and find some way to access the `Password` field, making the use of the `SecureString` value essentially useless?

I will admit, I have no clue how these exploits are executed.  However, if the problem is that some application might be sniffing your variables in the .Net memory manager/garbage collector, it would seem plausible to me that all they'd have to do is access the `PasswordBox` control object, rather than a string object in memory and simply access the `Password` property.  What might I be missing in this puzzle? How is the `PasswordBox` even secure if it contains a `Password` property in clear text?

Comment: there used to be winspy which would show you controls and visible properties Id not be surprised if there was something similar.  I will give you the words I read so much on similar subjects.  If people wanna crack it, they will. Theres next to nothing you can do to encrypt with seeds and codes that isnt going to be workable, unless its a one way encrypt and you just compare encrpyted items together not unencrypted because if theres a fixed seed.. its in your code to find, if its not fixed, it came from somewhere and can be intercepted or diverted, the harder you try so will they

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PasswordBox.Password` property creates .NET string from `SecurePassword` property, it does not store it as string internally. The whole point of using `SecureString` is to *reduce* amount of time sensetive data is present in memory, and reduce number of copies of that sensetive data. You can read more about `SecureString` in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx).

`SecureString` is encrypted (if possible, and usually it is), so if someone can just read raw memory (such as someone stealing your memory dump) - he will not be able to read your password from it. If your application is so compromised that attacker can inject his own dll into your process and run arbitrary code there - then you have bigger problems anyway (and still there is high chance that password will not be present in memory already).

That said, you can still follow some reasonable guidelines when using `PasswordBox` and `SecureString`s in general.

1. Always dispose result of `PasswordBox.SecurePassword` if you ever need to access it:

   ```
   using (var pwd = myBox.SecurePassword) {
       // do stuff
   }
   ```

This might look strange (disposing something returned by property), but it should be done, because this property returns a copy of `SecureString` and should have been a method instead, but for some reason is property.

2. Access `Password` property as rare as possible, preferrably only once when you really need it. You don't want copies of password to stay in memory more and longer than needed.
3. Always call `yourBox.Clear()` when you are done. This will set password to empty string and clear interal `SecureString` memory.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Point #3 probably addresses my concern.  My thought was that the `PasswordBox` could linger in the GC as some form of accessible control.  The `Clear()` method probably cleans up the content so that even the control object hangs around a while, the `SecureString` will have been rendered useless.

Comment: @RLH yes, but even before calling `Clear`, to access password inside `SecureString` attacker needs to execute code in your process (to `call` Password property for example), at which point you are doomed anyway. And `SecureString` is encrypted. So only password in plain text (as received from calling `Password`) is vulnerable if will stay in memory for too long.

Comment: I see, that helps clarify the situation.  I think I have enough information here to be ~dangerous~ capable of doing what I need to do.

Comment: @RLH and how are you going to use that password by the way?

Comment: There are actually a lot of uses for the PasswordBox in my application.  Quite tricky use case and considering the nature of the application, I'm probably not even allowed to state what type of information we collect from our users.

Comment: I can, and did, mention that one use if for acquiring a passphrase.  Specifically, we don't store that value, ever, but we do use if for localized encryption. I'm working on securing the encryption keys derived from the passphrase in memory now.  That's part of the process. We have many layers to this tool.

Comment: @RLH Ok, just wanted to mention that some parts of framework accept `SecureString` as is, without requiring you to convert it to regular string. For example, `SqlConnection` has `Credential` property which accepts it: `connection.Credential = new SqlCredential("user id", mySecureString);`

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I'll keep this in mind.  We are going through a major security overhaul/upgrade within this app.  I'll bring it up in standup today.  I think we have even more options than we were originally aware of.  The trickiest bits might come when we have to convert some of these values to encrypted string for use on non-Windows systems.  But, maybe there's a solution to that too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to take guesses, you can just [look it up](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,170).

The passwordbox has no field `Password`. It has a field [PasswordTextContainer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordTextContainer.cs,00a05511bd7deb7c,references) that keeps the password.

This means the documentation is correct that says

> Remarks
>
> When you get the Password property value, you expose the password as plain text in memory. To avoid this potential security risk, use the SecurePassword property to get the password as a SecureString.

If you don't read it as plaintext and keep it as plaintext in your app, it *won't be* plaintext.

But again, don't trust random people on the internet (including me!), [just look at it yourself](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs).

Comment: No you missed the point. I've read the documentation.  However, the `PasswordBox` control is an object in memory. If malicious code can read the .Net memory or GC and find the `PasswordBox` control, can't it just access the `Password` property.  Sure, the property probably does the leg work to extract the data, but if you can access the object in memory, I assume you could possibly still call the property, and have the .Net runtime extract the value for you.  I could be wrong. I don't know how exploits work. But having a property providing this value, in any form, seens problematic.

Comment: @RLH If you have a process that can tamper with your memory and execute code on it, there is **no** way to keep something safe. With that kind of privileges, *nothing* is safe.

Comment: mostly true. The only way I think it could be slightly-mitigated is if the process is using some form of DPAPI encryption at the user level. So long as malicious code isn't running under the given users context and the DPAPI API isn't doing local machine encryption there is an additional barrier blocking the the decryption. However, I 100% agree. Regardless, this app needs to do what ever it can to protect this data, even if the machine has been compromised. It's certainly a bit of cat-and-mouse, but we want to make it such that if there is an exploitable region, is very VERY isolated.